# PropertyChangedCallback is not getting fired during callback when a value in ViewModel is changed

Tags: xaml, mvvm, data-binding, dependency-properties, caliburn.micro

I have a view that uses the SearchBox user control, The SearchBox has two radio buttons to select the search modes - Instant and delayed. I have binded the  searchmodes to SearchMode property, and also I have created a custom dependency property for the Search Mode.

View

```
<controls:SearchBox Grid.Row="0"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right"
              Margin="2" Width="200"                           
              SearchMode="{Binding DataContext.SearchMode, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" />
```

ViewModel.cs

```
private Mode mSearchMode;
            public Mode SearchMode
            {
                get
                {
                    return mSearchMode;
                }
                set
                {
                    mSearchMode = value;
                    NotifyOfPropertyChange();
                }
            }

      // Called when application is restarted.
      private void ActivateLastSelectedSearchMode(Mode lastselectedMode)
            {    
               // Sets the last selected mode to the search mode      
                SearchMode =  lastselectedMode;
            }

         public enum Mode
            {
                Instant,
                Delayed,
            }
```

SearchBox.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class = "abc.SearchBox"
                 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >

   <UserControl.Resources>
            <converters:EnumToBooleanConverter x:Key="EnumToBooleanConverter" />
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
     <RadioButton Content="{lex:Loc SearchBox:SearchModelInstatOption}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Mode.Instant}}" />
     <RadioButton Content="{lex:Loc SearchBox:SearchModeDelayedOption}"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=SearchMode, Converter={StaticResource EnumToBooleanConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static local:Mode.Delayed}}" />
    </StackPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

SearchBox.xaml.cs

```
public partial class SearchBox : UserControl
    {
      public static DependencyProperty SearchModeProperty =
                    DependencyProperty.Register(
                        "SearchMode",
                        typeof(Mode),
                        typeof(SearchBox),
                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(Mode), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnIsSearchModeChanged));

    static void OnIsSearchModeChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
            {            
                var searchBox = obj as SearchBox;
                searchBox.SearchMode = (Mode)e.NewValue;                 

            }

              public Mode SearchMode
            {
                get { return (Mode)GetValue(SearchModeProperty); }
                set { SetValue(SearchModeProperty, value); }
            }

    }
```

I want the OnIsSearchModeChanged() to be fired each time when SearchMode is set during call back i e, ActivateLastSelectedSearchMode() is invoked in ViewModel.cs. I am absolutely clueless..where I am missing, I am unable to achieve success.

Answer (score 1):

```
//snip

    private Mode mSearchMode;
                public Mode SearchMode
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return mSearchMode;
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        mSearchMode = value;
                        NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>SearchMode); //Change
                 }
                }
```

does the reflected change make any difference?  Other option would be to create a custom convention for your user control

Answer (score 1):

You should create an Event in you View Model and subscribe to it from your code behind.

In your View Model :

```
 public event SearchModeAction SearchModeChanged;
 public delegate void SearchModeAction(object sender, EventArgs e);
 public void SearchModeHasChanged()
        {
            SearchModeAction Handler = SearchModeChanged;
            if (Handler != null)
            {
                Handler(this, null);
            }
        }
private void ActivateLastSelectedSearchMode(Mode lastselectedMode)
            {    
               // Sets the last selected mode to the search mode      
                SearchMode =  lastselectedMode;
                SearchModeHasChanged()
            }
```

In your Code Behind :

```
 private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           ((YourViewModelClass)DataContext).SearchModeChanged += OnIsSearchModeChanged;
        }

private void OnIsSearchModeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var searchBox = obj as SearchBox;
             searchBox.SearchMode = (Mode)e.NewValue;         
        }
```

This way each time you arrive in your ActivateLastSelectedSearchMode method in your View Model, you will call your OnIsSearchModeChanged method in your View.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh..the reason was the EnumToBooleanConverter.

Though the value of 'parameter' and 'value' was same, There was a difference between their object types as both were referencing to different namespaces. So I created a public enum called 'Mode' and ensured that the 'Instant' and 'Delayed' reference to the same namespace.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return value.Equals(parameter); // This always returned false despite the values being the same
        }
```